# ¿Por que Forms60 y Report6 no funcionan correctamente con mi configuración?

Tags: oracle, formularios, oracle-10g

¿Cómo hago para que el `fomrs60` de oracle y el `reports`, funcionen sobre la misma PC donde tengo la base de datos `11g` y me compile las formas?.

En la misma PC tengo instalada la base de datos `XE`, el `forms50` y el `reports`. Ellas trabajan con el mismo `TNSNAME.ORA`, pero a la hora de conectarme desde el `forms` o el `report`, esta no se conecta y me obliga a cerrar el forms o reports porque se queda pegada la aplicación.

Comment: La información que brindas es muy poca para que alguien con la intención de hacerlo pueda ayudarte realmente.

Dices que no funcionan con tu configuración, pero no muestras nada relevante de dicha configuración.

Tampoco comentas qué es lo que has intentado para resolver el problema, y los resultados que esto ha arrojado.

Comment: Que tipo y versión de OS estás usando?

Answer (score 2):

El verdadero problema es que Forms60 y Rerports60 ya están fuera de soporte, la última vez que funcionaron medio decentemente fue en Windows Vista... y tal vez ni eso.

Ese error de Forms colgado es porque ya es incompatible con el host que estas usando, como mucho lo que puedes hacer es configurar las propiedades de los ejecutables de forms y reports para que se ejecuten en modo de compatibilidad con Windows XP o el más antiguo que puedas. En adición tambien es recomendable  hacer que se ejecute con privilegios elevados.

Es lo más que podrás hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Solo puedo decirte que abras un sólo formulario desde el `forms` o el `reports`. Cuando tienes todo en el mismo ordenador me ha ocurrido que abriendo más de un formulario o informe, no se podía conectar a la base de datos y tenía que cerrarlos y volverlos a abrir. Esto me pasaba si el ordenador iba un poco justo.